# WPF Change property from codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a property being set as follows:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="lstDrop" Background="Transparent" GUICommon:ListBoxSelector.Enabled="True"
```

Could someone tell me if its possible to change the `GUICommon:ListBoxSelector.Enabled="True"` property to false in the codebehind?

Answer (score 0):

`ListBoxSelector.Enabled` seems to be an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

You should be able to set it by calling

```
ListBoxSelector.SetEnabled(lstDrop, true);
```